# How to get the old value when handling QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged() signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have a `QTableView` which have set a `QStandardItemModel`. The user edits data in some index in the view and then the model emits the `dataChanged()` signal. In the SLOT where I am handling the SIGNAL I have the `QModelIndex` range of the user changes and thus I can get the new values the user have entered. How can I obtain the old values at that point?

Comment: Have you really checked whether the indexes referred in the slot'a arguments contain new values and not the old ones?

Comment: Yes. This is why the signal is called dataChanged() and not "dataBeforeChange".

Comment: Well, but if the data is already changed, what you need the old one for?

Comment: @vahancho: This is irrelevant. Aparrently he needs an old data and that is that.

Comment: `QStandardItemModel` is a simple and general model. It does not have a signal with this feature. If you want such a feature you can subclass `QAbstractItemModel` and have your own custom class. Then in the class you should implement `setData` and emit a custom signal which contains both the old and the new values.

Comment: @Googie, it is a relevant question because if the framework has no such an API, than requesting this data (old one) does not make any sense, at least, when it is already changed. Knowing that makes sense **before** changing the data (f.e. as Nejat suggested) to compare the new and old values for verification.

Answer (score 3):

Since `QStandardItemModel` is a simple model, it does not have a signal with this feature. If you want such a feature you can subclass `QAbstractItemModel` and have your own custom class and implement `setData` and emit a custom signal which contains both the old and the new values.

As a workaround you can connect the `itemChanged` signal of `QStandardItemModel` to some slot :

```
connect(model,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)),this, SLOT(onModelChanged(QStandardItem*)));
```

And store the new value as a `Qt::UserRole` in model to use it as the old value when the slot is called next time :

```
void MyClass::onModelChanged(QStandardItem *item)
{

   disconnect(model,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)),this, SLOT(onModelChanged(QStandardItem*)));

   QVariant oldValue = item->data(Qt::UserRole);

   item->setData(item->data(Qt::DisplayRole), Qt::UserRole); //Store the new value for next use

   connect(model,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)),this, SLOT(onModelChanged(QStandardItem*)));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

User can change data with delegate so possible solution is:

```
#ifndef ITEMDELEGATE_H
#define ITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QItemDelegate>

class ItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget * editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;

signals:
    void dataChanged(QString oldValue,QString newValue) const;

public slots:
private:
     mutable QString old;//we want change member data in const method

};

#endif // ITEMDELEGATE_H
```

As you can see many methods are `const` by default so I did some tricks (such as `mutable`) to avoid problems. Also in my edited answer I doesn't store old data in `UserRole+1` , all done with old `mutable` variable.

cpp:

```
#include "itemdelegate.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDebug>

ItemDelegate::ItemDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *ItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QLineEdit *editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
    return editor;
}


void ItemDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                 const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    old = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();//store old data
    QLineEdit *line = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    line->setText(old);
}


void ItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor,
                                QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                const QModelIndex &index)const
{
    QLineEdit *line = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    QString data = line->text();

    emit dataChanged(old, line->text());
    model->setData(index, data);
}


void ItemDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
                                        const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                        const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Usage:

```
  ItemDelegate * del = new ItemDelegate;
   connect(del,&ItemDelegate::dataChanged,[=](QString oldValue,QString newValue) {
        qDebug() << "old" << oldValue<< "new" <<newValue ;
   });
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(del);
```

I tested it and it works. It will work with different models. `QTableView` uses `lineEdit` as delegate by default, so user will not see any changes in view.

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.

Answer (score 3):

After some research I figured out that there is no standard way to achive this behaviour. To solve the problem I had to inherit `QStandardItemModel` and reimplement `setData()` like this:

```
class RecallModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:
    RecallModel (QObject * parent = 0) : QStandardItemModel(parent) {}

    // Reimplemented
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role= Qt::EditRole)
    {
        // backup the previous model data
        if (role == Qt::EditRole || role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            QStandardItemModel::setData(index, data(index), Qt::UserRole + 1);

        return QStandardItemModel::setData(index, value, role);
    }
};
```

And after that I can access the old data in the slot handling the `dataChanged()` signal:

```
void SomeObject::handleDataChange(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight)
{
    ...
    const QVariant &vOldData = index.data(Qt::UserRole + 1); // here is the old data
    const QVariant &vNewData = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole); // here is the new data
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All solutions before this answer rely on Qt-specific features. But you can move INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE (not SQL, but common) functionality outside Qt framework. Look at *Unit Of Work* Design Pattern, and related *Domain Object* pattern from **"Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture"**.

You can modify this patterns to hold old values and get it when you modify during `setData()`.